# Create a menu from JSON Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, json

I want to create a menu from JSON Array

JSON Array:

```
[{
    "page_id":"102608802958096849","title":"Submenu 1 1","page_order":1,"parent_id":"305280635460611248","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-1-1.html"
},{
    "page_id":"207782958260361106","title":"Submenu 2 1","page_order":1,"parent_id":"196241715470310788","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-2-1.html"
},{
    "page_id":"305280635460611248","title":"Submenu 1","page_order":1,"parent_id":"308333626876055885","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-1.html"
},{
    "page_id":"308333626876055885","title":"Demo","page_order":1,"parent_id":null,"layout":"header-slider","page_url":"index.html"
},{
    "page_id":"357018431614169959","title":"Not Mega Menu","page_order":1,"parent_id":"756836287653398147","layout":"header","page_url":"not-mega-menu.html"
},{
    "page_id":"363544895956322795","title":"Submenu 2 1 1","page_order":1,"parent_id":"207782958260361106","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-2-1-1.html"
},{
    "page_id":"130518632716609153","title":"New Page","page_order":2,"parent_id":"756836287653398147","layout":"header","page_url":"new-page.html"
},{
    "page_id":"196241715470310788","title":"Submenu 2","page_order":2,"parent_id":"308333626876055885","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-2.html"
},{
    "page_id":"520778073299851538","title":"Submenu 2 2","page_order":2,"parent_id":"196241715470310788","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-2-2.html"
},{
    "page_id":"756836287653398147","title":"Phoenix","page_order":2,"parent_id":null,"layout":"header","page_url":"phoenix.html"
},{
    "page_id":"951287960823231869","title":"Submenu 2 1 2","page_order":2,"parent_id":"207782958260361106","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-2-1-2.html"
}]
```

The expected menu I want to create look similar like this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <a>Demo</a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Submenu 1</a>
                <div>
                    <ul><li><a>Submenu 1 1</a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>Submenu 2</a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a>Submenu 2 1</a>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a>Submenu 2 1 1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a>Submenu 2 1 2</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>Submenu 2 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <a>Phoenix</a>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>New Page</a></li>
            <li><a>Not Mega Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Note that:

With an example: "page_id":"102608802958096849","title":"Submenu 1 1","page_order":1,"parent_id":"305280635460611248","layout":"header","page_url":"submenu-1-1.html"

page_id = 102608802958096849 (define id of menu)

title = Submenu 1 1 (title)

page_order = 1 (menu:nth-child(1))

Any idea to build the menu above from JSON array ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Jup. Turn the array into a tree, than its simple to tansform it into a DOM tree.

Comment: I'm a newbie then I don't know how to get this. Can you help me to figure it out ? Thanks

Comment: I will do. Thank you

Comment: I had a look at your previous questions and they are all much better than this one. Just do what you did there (show what youve tried, explain were you got stuck etc.) and I will be glad to help you :)

Comment: Here are the things I've tried:

pages_json = (the JSON Array above)

var pages_json_string = JSON.parse(pages_json);

var pages_json_length = pages_json_string.length;

var submenu = "<li class='submenu-settings-parent'>"+title+"</li>";

for(i=0;i<pages_json_length;i++){
 if(pages_json_string[i]['parent_id']==page_id){
  submenu += "<li class='submenu-settings-child' page-id="+pages_json_string[i]['page_id']+">" + pages_json_string[i]['title'] + "</li>";
 }
}

$(this).parents('.mega_menu_box').find('.submenu-settings').empty().append(submenu);

Comment: I tried to create each main menu with this submenu first, then combine them into the large one. I encountered the stuck when create submenu level 2, level 3, ..., level n. I tried to use for loop but this seems even worse when using too many overlapping loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a tree first and then render the wanted structure.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach(a => {
        if (o[a.page_id] && o[a.page_id].children) {
            a.children = o[a.page_id] && o[a.page_id].children;
        }
        o[a.page_id] = a;
        o[a.parent_id] = o[a.parent_id] || {};
        o[a.parent_id].children = o[a.parent_id].children || [];
        o[a.parent_id].children.push(a);
    });
    return o.null.children;
}

function buildMenu(array, target) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');

    array.forEach(o => {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            a = document.createElement('a'),
            div;

        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.title));
        a.href = o.page_url;
        li.appendChild(a);
        if (o.children) {
            div = document.createElement('div');
            buildMenu(o.children, div);
            li.appendChild(div);
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    target.appendChild(ul);
}

var data = [{ page_id: "102608802958096849", title: "Submenu 1 1", page_order: 1, parent_id: "305280635460611248", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-1-1.html" }, { page_id: "207782958260361106", title: "Submenu 2 1", page_order: 1, parent_id: "196241715470310788", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-2-1.html" }, { page_id: "305280635460611248", title: "Submenu 1", page_order: 1, parent_id: "308333626876055885", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-1.html" }, { page_id: "308333626876055885", title: "Demo", page_order: 1, parent_id: null, layout: "header-slider", page_url: "index.html" }, { page_id: "357018431614169959", title: "Not Mega Menu", page_order: 1, parent_id: "756836287653398147", layout: "header", page_url: "not-mega-menu.html" }, { page_id: "363544895956322795", title: "Submenu 2 1 1", page_order: 1, parent_id: "207782958260361106", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-2-1-1.html" }, { page_id: "130518632716609153", title: "New Page", page_order: 2, parent_id: "756836287653398147", layout: "header", page_url: "new-page.html" }, { page_id: "196241715470310788", title: "Submenu 2", page_order: 2, parent_id: "308333626876055885", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-2.html" }, { page_id: "520778073299851538", title: "Submenu 2 2", page_order: 2, parent_id: "196241715470310788", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-2-2.html" }, { page_id: "756836287653398147", title: "Phoenix", page_order: 2, parent_id: null, layout: "header", page_url: "phoenix.html" }, { page_id: "951287960823231869", title: "Submenu 2 1 2", page_order: 2, parent_id: "207782958260361106", layout: "header", page_url: "submenu-2-1-2.html" }],
    tree = getTree(data);

buildMenu(tree, document.body);

console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should nest the child objects. It's going to make your life easier (and also this is the right way to do it).

```
[
  "Submenu 1": {
    "page_url": "one.html",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "item": "Submenu 1-1",
        "page_url": "one-one.html",
      },
      {
        "item": "Submenu 1-2",
        "page_url": "one-two.html",
      }
    ],
  },
  "Submenu 2": {
    "page_url": "two.html",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "item": "Submenu 2-1",
        "page_url": "two-one.html",
      },
      {
        "item": "Submenu 2-2",
        "page_url": "two-two.html",
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Then you can loop through the submenu items and it's child links

Comment: Does this mean I need to categorize each child object of a parent object, then split it into different arrays? What if there are 10 levels in the same menu parents object? I'm making a mega menu based on this json file. And it really is not possible to know exactly how many submenu levels in each json file

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to do loops inside loops. In the last applications i've been working on we're using .map() inside other .map() to generate components and stuff.

If you cant change the structure of the JSON, i suggest you to make a function to loop through all content, generate a nested object and then build your markup tags. Since you have a `parent_id` in your json, that should be enought to build the new object

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I realized the way I tried was stupid :)).

Answer (score 0):

At first we have to relate nodes to their parents, building up a tree:

```
 const hash = {}, root = [];
 // Go over the array and destructure it:
 for(const {page_url, title, page_id, parent_id} of array) {
    // Add this node to the hashtable:
    let el;
    if(hash[page_id]) {
      el = Object.assign(hash[page_id], {page_url, title});
    } else {
      el = hash[page_id] = {page_url, title, children: []};
    }

    // Link parents / children
    if(parent_id) {
      if(hash[parent_id]) {
         hash[parent_id].children.push(el);
      } else {
         hash[parent_id] = { children: [ el ] };
      }
   } else {
      root.push(el);
   }
}
```

Now `root` contains a list of root elements, and each of them has a `children` array that contains elements with childrens and so on. Now its quite simple to build a DOM tree recursively:

```
 function buildRecursively(array) {
   const container = document.createElement("li");
   for(const el of array) {
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.textContent = el.title;
      link.href = el.page_url;
      container.appendChild(link);
      container.appendChild(buildRecursively(el.children));
   }
  return container;
}
```

So you can just do:

```
 document.body.appendChild(buildRecursively(root));
```